Access sharepoint file using python and AAD
I want to access sharepoint file using python and AAD(Azuer Active Directory) app.
Is their any way for that?
I want access subfolders also. Need not download files locally. Is their any python packages available for this.

You can use the Microsoft Graph API to access SharePoint. Specific details on how to use this (like authentication and things) you can find on the internet.

Yes, their is a python package called sharejeeni.
Install sharejeeni pip install sharejeeni.
import sharejeeni

client_id = "xxxx-xx-xxx-xx-xxxx"
client_secret = "xxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
tenant_id = "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"
    
sharepoint_url =  "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com"
Site_name = "TrialSite" # sharepoint site name
domain = "xxxx.sharepoint.com"

folder = 'Trial_Folder' #Folder name
subfolder = 'SubTrial_Folder' #Subfolder name
file = "subfile.csv" #File name
save_as = "savedfile.csv"
token = sharejeeni.request_token(tenant_id,client_secret,client_id)
site = sharejeeni.get_site(token,Site_name,domain)
sharejeeni.Get().file(file,token,site,save_as)

for file inside folder
sharejeeni.Get().folder(folder).file(file,token,site,save_as)

for file in subfolders
sharejeeni.Get().folder(folder).subfolder(subfolder).file(file,token,site,save_as)

